# How do I get the path to your the iPhone resources folder?

Tags: iphone, resources, path, directory

I am currently using [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]. Is there a different way to do this?

Comment: Why? This way is not good enough?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably way too late to help you, but yes, there are LOTS of different ways to do this. Look at some of the methods on the `NSURL` class. I think that "paths are strings but URLs are not" can be pretty confusing.